# a method always returns false even if i enter valid values

Tags: java

in this method i have tried to set row =0 , row =1 row =2 row =3 row =4 and the result is always false. i think its something considering the initilization of the variable valid but if i do not initialize the compiler comes up with error

```
  public static boolean isValidMove(int row,int col){
    boolean valid=false;
   if(row>=0&&row<3&&col>=0&&col<3){
        if (takenSquare[row][col]==false) {
            valid= true;
        }
   }
```

Comment: The code you are showing does not attempt to return anything at all.

Comment: I assume you have a `return valid;` at the end, right?

Comment: This is not the method you called because it does not compile! Please fix!

Comment: There are many things that could explain the false result, including the rest of the isValidMove method, out of range row or col, or a true value in takenSquare. I suggest an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: I'm really Shocked!! without returning anything you are getting "false" every time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your condition is never evaluated at all

```
public static boolean isValidMove( int nRow,int nCol ) {

    boolean blValid = false;

    if( ( nRow >= 0 && nRow < 3 ) && ( nCol >= 0 && nCol < 3 ) ) {

        if ( arTakenSquare[ nRow ][ nCol ] == false ) {

            blValid = true;

        }
    }

    return blValid;
}
```

May be this would help.

Comment: Other than the missing `return` and slightly changed names, this appears identical to the original code?

Comment: You missed parenthesis in the conditional statement. My guess is that the condition statement is not executed as expected

Comment: There could be great many reasons for why the function doesn't work the way OP expects, but the parentheses are not one of them.

Comment: Agreed. Just thought of making the code more readable. Since the question itself is not much clear, just mentioned a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid (for values from 0 to 2). Of course you need a return statment. The only thing that can be wrong is takenSquare[row][col]==false. Is that a array of boolean values?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an extension to my comment suggesting an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). I have taken the code from the question, and wrapped it in a simple test program. To complete the isValidMove method I added a return of `valid` and a `}`.

It prints `row=0, col=0: true`. This confirms the bug is not in the code quoted in the question.

The next step is for the OP to either modify this until it reproduces the problem, or simplify the rest of the OP's program until it is about this long. Either way, the objective is a short, simple program that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem. Often, the attempt write such a thing will bring out the bug. If it does not, posting the SSCCE will certainly get a useful answer.

```
public class Test
{
  private static boolean[][] takenSquare = new boolean[3][3];

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("row=0, col=0: "+isValidMove(0,0));
  }

  public static boolean isValidMove(int row, int col) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (row >= 0 && row < 3 && col >= 0 && col < 3) {
      if (takenSquare[row][col] == false) {
        valid = true;
      }
    }
    return valid;
  }
}
```

================================================================

Here's a revised version of my test program that demonstrates instrumenting isValidMove so that it is clear what arguments it was passed, what it is returning, and why it is returning false any time it does so.

```
public class Test
{
  private static boolean[][] takenSquare = new boolean[3][3];

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    takenSquare[1][1] = true;
    test(0,0);
    test(0,-1);
    test(1,1);
  }

  private static void test(int row, int col){
    System.out.println("Test result: row="+row+", col="+col+", valid="+isValidMove(row, col));
  }

  public static boolean isValidMove(int row, int col) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (row >= 0 && row < 3 && col >= 0 && col < 3) {
      if (takenSquare[row][col] == false) {
        valid = true;
      } else {
        System.out.println("isValidMove square already taken for row="+row+", col="+col);
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("isValidMove out of range argument row="+row+" col="+col);
    }
    System.out.println("Returning "+valid+" from isValidMove("+row+","+col+")");
    return valid;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3183162 You need to learn basic debug skills, including simplifying your code and using debug or print statements to localize a bug. See [my debug notes](http://patriciashanahan.com/debug/index.html) for some ideas.

Comment: i am in the first semester  in cs..im kinda noob

Comment: Maybe you need to take smaller steps. Take a short, absolutely minimum subset of your program, with a tiny piece of the target functionality, and get it working correctly. Then add more features, testing each step as you go along.

Comment: @user3183162 I've posted a new version of my test program that shows how to instrument isValidMove to collect the information you need to find out what is going on and why it is returning false, if it does so. You can use that in the context of your existing code to get some clues about your problem.